# Merge (with squash) all changes from another branch as a single commit

Tags: git

In Git, is there a way to merge all changes from one branch into another, but squash to a single commit at the same time?

I often work on a new feature in a separate branch and will regularly commit/push - mainly for backup or to transfer what I'm working on to another machine.  Mostly those commits say "Feature xxx WIP" or something redundant.

Once that work is finished and I want to merge WIP branch back into master, I'd like to discard all those intermediate commits, and just a have a single clean commit.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Alternatively, how about a command that squashes all commits on a branch since the point where it was branched?

Answer (score 779, accepted):

Another option is `git merge --squash <feature branch>` then finally do a `git commit`.

From [Git merge](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

> `--squash`
>
> `--no-squash`
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge
>   happened (except for the merge
>   information), but do not actually make
>   a commit or move the `HEAD`, nor record
>   `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to cause the next
>   `git commit` command to create a merge
>   commit. This allows you to create a
>   single commit on top of the current
>   branch whose effect is the same as
>   merging another branch (or more in
>   case of an octopus).

Comment: Cool feature! I love git. While I'll definitely be using this in the future now, I'd still recommend getting to know your way around rebase -i. It's a good skill to have, just in case you really did want to make them more than just one commit.

Comment: A word of caution: this works, but the default commit message includes the log from the branch being merged. The problem is it looks similar to the format you normally see where the entire text shown does not actually become part of the commit message, but in this case it does. So if you don't want all that, you need manually remove all of it from your commit message. I should have tested this before using it...

Comment: That, and, be warned that the branch will not be seen as merged. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308790/git-branch-merged-no-merged-and-squash-option

Comment: IMHO this should have been called `rebase --squash`

Comment: so (since it does not really merge the feature branch) this would be appropriate if you were going to delete the feature branch after commit. Is that correct? (I am not a git expert)

Comment: Ok this only works on branch basis as requested in the question (=whole branch). I needed this for a sum of commits only and so I couldn't use this.

Comment: Worked very well, creating a single commit from the feature branch (with multiple commits and merges before) to the main branch. Clean approach and gives you flexibility to revert everything in one go if anything goes wrong!

Answer (score 285):

Found it!  Merge command has a `--squash` option

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash WIP
```

at this point everything is merged, possibly conflicted, but not committed.  So I can now:

```
git add .
# git add -u  # might be preferable, see below
git commit -m "Merged WIP"
```

Comment: what does the `git add .` do?

Comment: @MichaelPotter It adds all the files and changes

Comment: `git add .` adds all non-ignored files in the current directory, I would be wary of picking up unintended files this way.

Comment: As an alternate to `git add .` you can use `git add -u` to only add files which have been already added to the tree.

Comment: Suggesting that a "git add ." be also done is confusing. When I do the "git merge --squash WIP", it already has the squashed changes in the index. All that is needed is to commit them. Doing a "git add ." will add changes that happen to be in the working directory, but which were not part of the feature branch. The question was how to commit the changes in the feature branch as one commit.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I needed. Except, I first created a new feature branch off of master, so that I could create a PR off of this feature branch. Then I merged the old feature branch into this (as specified). And as someone else said, everything was already staged. I just need to commit.

Comment: @JohnPankowicz This is not true for merge conflicts. While `git add .` is still sub-optimal because it could pull in unintended files, if there were merge conflicts, any involved files will need to be added before they can be committed.

Answer (score 38):

Try `git rebase -i master` on your feature branch.  You can then change all but one 'pick' to 'squash' to combine the commits.  See [squashing commits with rebase](http://www.gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

Finally, you can then do the merge from master branch.

Comment: Yes that works, but I don't want the hassle of interactive rebase.  I just want everything since the branch flattened.

Comment: +1 This makes for a clean history. It's a lot easier to identify and manage commits as individual patches, cards, stories, etc.

Answer (score 27):

Using `git merge --squash <feature branch>` as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3697263/2996101) suggests does the trick but it will not show the merged branch as actually merged.

Therefore an even better solution is to:

- Create a new branch from the <del>latest master</del>, commit in the master branch where the feature branch initiated.
- Merge `<feature branch>` into the above using `git merge --squash`
- Merge the newly created branch into master. This way, the feature branch will contain only one commit and the merge will be represented in a short and tidy illustration.

[This wiki](https://github.com/rotati/wiki/wiki/Git:-Combine-all-messy-commits-into-one-commit-before-merging-to-Master-branch) explains the procedure in detail.

In the following example, the left hand screenshot is the result of `qgit` and the right hand screenshot is the result of:

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

**Both** screenshots show the same range of commits in the same repository. Nonetheless, the right one is more compact thanks to `--squash`.

- Over time, the `master` branch deviated from `db`.
- When the `db` feature was ready, a new branch called `tag` was created in the same commit of `master` that `db` has its root.
- From `tag` a `git merge --squash db` was performed and then all changes were staged and committed in a single commit.
- From `master`, `tag` got merged: `git merge tag`.
- The branch `search` is irrelevant and not merged in any way.

[image]

Comment: This, for me, is actually much nicer way than doing `git rebase -i master` and playing with the interactive mode. Easy to remember and easy to work with.

Answer (score 9):

## 2020 updated

With the `--squash` flag it looks like two parallel branches with no relation:

[image]

Sorting commits related to date looks like:

[image]

Personally, i don't like --squash option, try this trick, maybe it fits your needs, i use it for small projects:

1. git init
2. git checkout -b dev
3. Several commits in dev
4. After you did some great commits in dev(but not merged to master yet), if you do not want all commits copied to master branch, then make intentionally change something in master and (add some empty lines in README file and commit in master),
5. git merge dev
   It results merge conflict(empty lines in README), resolve it, commit with new message you want, and you are DONE. Here is the visual representation of it.

null commit for intentionally merge conflict, name it anything you prefer

[image: null commit for intentionally merge conflict]

Comment: The idea, is to keep the [history linear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56179936/2996101). However, If a merge should be visible in the graph, it can be presented with [one commit only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714645/2996101) to avoid the clutter of all micro-commits produced during development. However, if all commits are desired in the graph, `merge` does the trick natively.

Comment: It seems wrong to intentionally create merge conflicts because your graphical representation is not nice. Just use a different representation instead of merge conflicts if you think it's necessary to have those small connection lines in your graphic.

Answer (score 5):

I have created my own git alias to do exactly this. I'm calling it `git freebase`! It will take your existing messy, unrebasable feature branch and recreate it so that it becomes a new branch with the same name with its commits squashed into one commit and rebased onto the branch you specify (master by default). At the very end, it will allow you to use whatever commit message you like for your newly "freebased" branch.

Install it by placing the following alias in your .gitconfig:

```
[alias]
  freebase = "!f() { \
    TOPIC="$(git branch | grep '\\*' | cut -d ' ' -f2)"; \
    NEWBASE="${1:-master}"; \
    PREVSHA1="$(git rev-parse HEAD)"; \
    echo "Freebaseing $TOPIC onto $NEWBASE, previous sha1 was $PREVSHA1"; \
    echo "---"; \
    git reset --hard "$NEWBASE"; \
    git merge --squash "$PREVSHA1"; \
    git commit; \
  }; f"
```

Use it from your feature branch by running:
`git freebase <new-base>`

I've only tested this a few times, so read it first and make sure you want to run it. As a little safety measure it does print the starting sha1 so you should be able to restore your old branch if anything goes wrong.

I'll be maintaining it in my dotfiles repo on github:
https://github.com/stevecrozz/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig

Comment: worked like a bliss! you might as well take a look at https://www.evernote.com/shard/s52/sh/7f8f4ff1-9a68-413f-9225-c49e3ee2fafd/8efbe48e76710ac51cf0fe9cdd10dbcd

Comment: This requires `grep` and therefore would need some additional tweaking in Windows.

Comment: +1 this is very elegant. For a similar implementation of this idea which adds some more features, bells & whistles, see https://github.com/arielf/clean-push

Answer (score 4):

You have a master branch and feature branch. You have lots of commits on a feature branch. You don't want all commits of the feature branch to appear on the master's commit history. Follow these steps

1. Create a new branch from the latest master code and you are in that branch

> ```
> git checkout -b latest_MCode
> ```

2. Now merge your feature branch into latest_Mcode branch

> ```
> git merge --squash feature
> ```

3. Do commit without -m param

> git commit # without -m

An editor should be a popup with all the commit logs, and files changed from the feature branch. You can see all feature branch commits here. If you want you can delete everything, and write only one line of the commit message you want to show after merging into master. Press i then write your message then press Esc->:wq->Enter to Save and quit the editor.
4. Merge your newly created branch into master

```
git checkout master
git merge latest_Mcode
git push
```

You are done!
The original answer can be found at [GithubLink](https://github.com/rotati/wiki/wiki/Git:-Combine-all-messy-commits-into-one-commit-before-merging-to-Master-branch)

Answer (score -1):

`git merge --squash <feature branch>` is a good option .The "git commit" tells you all feature branch commit message with your choice to keep it .

For less commit merge .

git merge 
do x times --git reset HEAD^ --soft
then git commit .

Risk - deleted files may come back .

Answer (score -8):

You can do this with the "rebase" command. Let's call the branches "main" and "feature":

```
git checkout feature
git rebase main
```

The rebase command will replay all of the commits on "feature" as one commit with a parent equal to "main".

You might want to run `git merge main` before `git rebase main` if "main" has changed since "feature" was created (or since the most recent merge). That way, you still have your full history in case you had a merge conflict.

After the rebase, you can merge your branch to main, which should result in a fast-forward merge:

```
git checkout main
git merge feature
```

See the [rebase](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/git-5.shtml) page of [Understanding Git Conceptually](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/) for a good overview

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I just created a simple test repo, with a WIP branch and tried the above and got merge conflicts (even though I hadn't made any changes on master).

Comment: If feature was created from main (git checkout -b feature main) and you had a recent merge from main, you shouldn't get conflicts from the rebase

Comment: OK, tried it again. Didn't get conflicts this time, but the history wasn't squashed.

Comment: Taking another look at the git-merge documentation, you are right, some of the commits will stay. If you have done previous merges from "main" to "feature" then the rebase will remove some of them, but not all.

Comment: Just remember that rebasing may be quite dangerous if the feature branch has been previously published. More info on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715085/rebasing-and-what-does-one-mean-by-rebasing-pushed-commits).

Comment: Mate, you don't need to merge if you are rebasing. Probably you got confused by git lens.