# Git branch --merged / --no-merged and --squash option

Tags: git, merge, squash

`git branch --merged` doesn't appear to play nicely with --squash.

If you do a normal `git merge`, then `git branch --merged` tells you which branches have been merged. This is not the case however if the --squash option is used, even though the resulting tree is the same.

I doubt this is a git defect and would like to know if there is some git-fu I'm missing, or if I have misunderstood something.

In short: I want to use --squash, but also want git to tell me if the branch I squashed into another one has been --merged.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't get there from here (as the fellow giving directions said).  More precisely, it does not make sense.

The problem is that `git merge --squash` does not actually do a merge.  Suppose your branch history looks like this, for instance (with branches `topic` and `devel`):

```
          H ⬅ I ⬅ J     <-- topic
        ⬋
⬅ F ⬅ G
        ⬉
          K ⬅ L         <-- devel
```

If you check out `devel` and merge `topic` you get a new merge commit `M` that contains the result of the merge, and `M` has two parents:

```
          H ⬅ I ⬅ J     <-- topic
        ⬋         ⬆
⬅ F ⬅ G           ⬆
        ⬉         ⬆
          K ⬅ L ⬅ M     <-- devel
```

But if you use `git merge --squash topic` you get, instead, a new commit (let's label it `S` for squash):

```
          H ⬅ I ⬅ J     <-- topic
        ⬋
⬅ F ⬅ G
        ⬉
          K ⬅ L ⬅ S     <-- devel
```

where (as you already noted) the *contents* (the tree) of commit `S` makes all the files come out the same as they would in commit `M`.  But there's no back-link (parent arrow) from S to `topic`.  It's not a merge at all, it's just taking all the changes from `topic`, squashing them into a single change, and adding that as an entirely independent commit.

Now, the other thing about `git merge --squash` is that it does not make the final commit.  So you could create the `.git` files that git would on a "regular" merge, and do a commit that has the two parents you'd get on a "real" merge.  And then you'd get ... exactly what you get if you run `git merge topic`, a commit (label it `S` or `M`, it does not matter) that has the same tree again, but now has two parent-arrows, pointing to `L` and `J`, just like `M`.

In fact, running `git merge --squash` is almost exactly the same as running `git merge --no-commit`, except for the tracing files left behind when the merge is done (`git commit` uses some of these to set up the parents).  The `squash` version does not write to `.git/MERGE`, `.git/MERGE_HEAD`, and `.git/MERGE_MODE`.  (It does create `.git/MERGE_MSG`, the same as `git merge --no-commit`, and it also creates `.git/SQUASH_MSG`.)

So, basically, you have your choice: a real merge (two or more parents on the final commit), or a squash (same tree-combining mechanisms, but only one parent on the final commit).  And, since `git branch --merged` works by looking at the "parent arrows" of each commit stored in the repository, only a real merge is really a merge, so only a real merge can be discovered later by `git branch`.

Comment: Your arrows(?) between commits in your graph do not render correctly in all browsers / operating systems.  I see a question mark.

Comment: Good answer, thank you for the explanation. I thought git would be able to squash the commit and still perform a three-way merge, oh well. I feel that `git merge --squash` is slightly misleading; I would have opted for a dedicated `git squash`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson: yes, I tried some arrows.  I imagine it's more a font thing than browser and/or OS though.  Oh well, I'll go back to plain old ASCII for the next diagram :-)

Comment: I never use `git merge --squash`, but I do frequently use `git log --first-parent`.