# "Merge" 2 Git Branches, ignoring the original commits

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have a simple scenario:

2 branches: **master** and **myownb**:

**myownb** is ahead of the **master** branch with 3 commits:

What I need is to "merge" these 2 branches, but not in the classic mode.

I would like all these 3 commits from **myownb** to be pushed as only one commit to the **master** branch (and preferably with a different commit message).

Or to create a patch of all the differences between these 2 branches, to be later applied to my master branch, and commit as I wish.

Comment: That's a straight example of what git calls a "squash merge" (which is not actually a merge at all): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2427238/1256452 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/19308790/1256452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in this instance is perform an interactive rebase. This will allow you to do everything you mentioned (squash to one commit, and provide a different commit message).

From `myownb` you would write `git rebase -i HEAD~3` because you're 3 commits ahead of when you branched off of `master`. In the dialog box that appears you should see your 3 commits in order, something like:

[image: interactive rebase screen]

You have to `pick` one so that the others have a basis with which to be squashed, for the second and third commits change `pick` to `s` or `squash`. Once you've done that save and quit the file. Once you've done that the commit message window will pop up.

[image]

In this window is where you'll be able to write your single commit message. Delete all of the generic messages that it gives and write your single commit message. Once you've done that, save and quit the file.

Back in your terminal you should be all set. Running a `git log` you'll see that all you have now are the commits leading up to master, and then a single commit with those three commits you had previously.

To finish, `git checkout master` and then `git merge myownb`