# git branch stash commits into one

Tags: git, github

Folks,
  I am trying to merge several commits in my branch into one before pushing to github.  Branch name is `mybranch`.

The following command should provide me with options to squash commits if I am not mistaking.

```
git rebase -i mybranch
```

I dont see it actually working...  It just says

```
noop

# Rebase 39e50c2..39e50c2 onto 39e50c2
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
...
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: [Git: merge all changes from another branch as a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697178/git-merge-all-changes-from-another-branch-as-a-single-commit)

Comment: @RomanGotsiy Im specifically trying to stay on one branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase moves commits from one place to another in the commit graph, so you can't rebase a branch onto itself because that would be a noop - like the message says. Instead, while on mybranch, what you probably want to do is rebase to the branch that it diverged from. For example, if it diverged from master, you need

```
git rebase -i master
```

Take a look at the "Feature/Bugfix Branch Workflow" on my cheatsheet for further info http://philipdaniels.com/gitcheatsheet/

In particular, if other people are pushing changes to your repo, it would be a good idea to understand why it is advisable to rebase onto origin/master (step 7): it forces you to resolve any merge conflicts at that time.

Answer (score 2):

You actually can't **merge** commits staying on one branch. But you can accomplish it using following steps:

```
# reset all changes after commit that already is pushed to remote repo
# option --soft will save all the changes in stage area 
git reset --soft origin/mybranch
# here all you changes is in stage area so you can commit
git commit -m "squashed commit"
git push
```

For a better understanding format of command [git reset](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) is:

```
git reset <mode> <commit>
```

And mode `--soft`:

> --soft Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do). This leaves all
>   your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put
>   it.

and `origin/mybranch` points to last pushed to origin commit.

If your `mybranch` is local branch (i.e. wasn't pushed to remote) you may reset to the branch that it diverged from.