# Why does my git log graph grow one more line after I merge a branch each time?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I'am used to use `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all` as alias `git ll` to see the graph of commits in terminal

But a problem confuse me when every single time I merge my `develop` to `master`.
The output of the command above may be like this:

```
* 0d1bf7b (HEAD -> master) Fix typo
*   f843224 Merge 'develop' to 'master'
|\
* | d673b76 (origin/master) Remove console.log for license information
* | 5080afc Remove all http url in production
* |   f28e74b Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \
* \ \   75c5b90 Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \ \
* \ \ \   ec189e6 Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \ \ \
* \ \ \ \   eb79c75 Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \ \ \ \
* \ \ \ \ \   74631ef Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \ \ \ \ \
| | | | | | | * f7a4155 (light) Fix typo
| | | | | | | *   1d6c411 Merge 'develop' to 'light'
| | | | | | | |\
| | | | | | | |/
| | | | | | |/|
| | | | | | * | 3715f47 (develop) Finish GroupCard in Setting page
| | | | | | | * e606e68 (origin/light) Remove console.log for license information
| | | | | | | * 676774c Remove all http url in production
| | | | | | | * c1bef16 Fix api url error
```

You can see there are too many lines generated after I merge `develop` to `master`. It is not a big problem for now, but it will become too many lines too obstruct me to see the commits someday.

So is there any thing I do wrong?
Have you guys ever faced kind of this problem?
How do you handle it?

---

#### [Editing on 2019/05/20]

Thank you guys. I appreciate your kind answers.

I want to fix my problem and make it clear a little bit.
I use some GUI tools like Source tree and it show the git log as below.
There are not many complicated lines with the same repository in this graph as you can see.

So is it possible if I want to show the graph like it in my command line interface?

[image: git log in Source tree]

Comment: I don't see anything necessarily unexpected here.  You repeatedly merge `develop` into `master`, but not vice versa.  Hence, the graph is showing that each merge commit has different branch parent in `develop`.  If you showed the full graph, you would probably see that all parents lie on the same branch.

Comment: Are there many merges from develop to light? Perhaps you should try to remove "--all" parameter. *Never* merging back to develop *and* regularly merging to master *and* merging to light *and* displaying master and light at the same time makes the graph a little bit complicated, I think.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand that it's a very useful message showing each merge commit, but if there are more than three branches in my repository, I' afraid of it will be very complicated to see whole picture of the git log.

Comment: @Marcus It is a nice suggestion when seeing only one branch, I think that is a alternative way if I didn't use other methods to keep my whole git log clear.

Comment: If you are starting many parallel branches, this is the result you will get.

Answer (score 2):

That is why [squash and rebase](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2017/08/28/always-squash-and-rebase-your-git-commits/) do exists (for local commits of develop you have not pushed yet).
That would help keep the history linear, instead of git log showing you each develop merge in its separate track.

> So is it possible if I want to show the graph like it in my command line interface?

In command-line, you can avoid all those extra lines by adding [`--no-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---no-merges):

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --no-merges --all --branches
```

Comment: I 100% agree on the rebase side, which make a log cleaner and easier to read. However, I would not advocate systematic squash to have a single commit merged. I prefer to keep the atomicity of commits even when they are merged, helping running bisects for example to find faulty merged commits. Merging a parent branch in a child branch (master in develop), or not rebasing develop after merging it in master create a flood of unusable information in the graph, but systematically squashing before merging removes valuable information, in my opinion.

Comment: @padawin I agree. I mention squash as one of the tools (with rebase) to help manage the history, but applying it systematically would be, indeed, detrimental to a useful history.

Comment: @VonC I think squash and rebase that you suggested is what I want to know, but I found my 'develop' will be stay with 'master' without a separated position after I rebase 'develop' to 'master'. Does that mean that if I want to keep my git log clear, I cannot go with a separated 'develop' in my git flow?

Comment: @ChrisKao Sure, you can have a separated `develop` in your git flow. It simply will look like in line with `master` after each rebase, but will start branching again at the next commit done in `develop`.

Comment: @ChrisKao Following your edited question, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Although that command works not 100% like Source Tree in my laptop, It is still useful answer for me to check the non-merge  commits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should use rebase and squash wherever applicable.
Additionally, you can try following --no-merges option like:

`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all --no-merges`

Comment: In this way, although it hide the lines of graph, it hide too many branch information as well.