# Git track two histories at the same time for multiple origins

Tags: git

Basically what I want is to have a repo for my dev team where they can push their code and make as many commits as they want.
Let's say this is the **dirty** repo.
I want to have another **clean** repo, where maybe once a week I will just pull their code and upload all the changes till now as one commit and name it how I want.

I do not want their history, but I want to keep the changes as a seperate history in the **clean** repo. I checked out for shallow repos but I don't think it's the same thing.
So far I've added a second origin to my project and I do git pull **origin** master and then git push **clean** master. But that pushes the history too, I want the same thing, but to track a seperate history.

Comment: Does this answer your question? Building on top of repo with dirty and clean origin you can squash-merge multiple commits from dirty as single commit to clean. [Merge (with squash) all changes from another branch as a single commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697178/merge-with-squash-all-changes-from-another-branch-as-a-single-commit)

Answer (score 0):

> [...] I've added a second origin to my project and I do git pull origin master and then git push clean master.

I like `git pull origin master` because then you always get the complete history from your team.

Instead of going straight to `git push clean master`, you could checkout a separate branch locally, let's call it `production`, which tracks `master` on the `clean` remote. Then, you `git merge master` to get all new changes, and `git rebase -i clean/master` to rebase all new commits on top of what you pushed the last time to `clean`.

While interactively rebasing, you're seeing exactly the commits that you are about to squash into a single commit, and it lets you include the commit message of the commits into your single squashed commit.

After rebasing, you can go ahead and `git push clean master`.

Answer (score 0):

The pieces of Git that are at odds with your desires are these:

- Git commits are universally unique.  Each commit has a unique hash ID, different from that of every other commit.
- A Git *repository* is, primarily, a collection of commits, which may be shared with other repositories; if two repositories have commits that have the same hash ID, those are literally the same commits.<sup>1</sup>
- A repository also has branch names: these names are not necessarily shared with any other repository.  Each branch name holds **one** (1) hash ID.  These serve to find some particular commit.  Git calls these the *tip* commits of the branches.  By definition, such a commit is the *last* commit in some chain of commits.
- *History*, in a Git repository, **is** the commits in the repository.  This comes about because one of the unalterable components *in* each commit is the raw hash ID of some *earlier* commit or commits.

What this means for you is that when you obtain commits from `origin`, those *commits* are inviolable and *are* history; their place in history is wherever they are in the chain that ends at some commit found by some name.  Let's say, for concreteness, that you've obtained a commit whose hash ID is `a123456` (actual hash IDs are larger and random-looking but this will serve here).

*Any* repository that has commit `a123456` therefore has *all the history that leads up to* `a123456`.<sup>2</sup>  If you send commit `a123456` to any other repository, it's your responsibility to send all the commits leading up to it, as well.<sup>3</sup>  That's why you end up sending the entire history to your remote named `clean`.

What **this** means for you is that if you want to have a different *history* in the repository you're calling `clean`, you must make a different set of *commits*.  These commits, being different, *are* different history.  There's a [flaw in this ointment](https://malaphors.com/2013/03/26/that-was-the-only-flaw-in-the-ointment/), which is that because these histories *are* unrelated, management of this new set of commits becomes very painful.  You *can* do it, it's just that Git won't be terribly helpful.  (You'll probably want to set up some naming scheme that keeps track of which commits you have already copied, and hence which ones you'll need to copy into `clean` as different commits.  Once they're copied, you will update these "copy-tracking names", whatever you end up calling them, perhaps `refs/copied/name` to go with `refs/heads/name`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>This is why two commits that are different, but have the same hash ID, are verboten in a repository.  I like to call such commits *doppelgängers*, with the evil connotation.  Git will refuse to add one, modulo any bugs.  See also [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)

<sup>2</sup>As a soft kind of exception, a *shallow* clone has *some* of the history leading up to here, with a cut-off "graft point" at which the repository just sort of shrugs its shoulders and says: *I know the commit that comes before this has hash ID* H *but I have been told not to get* H *so I don't have it*.  But any repository that *does* have the commit with hash ID H has the one that has *that* place in history, so it's the same history, it's just not *viewable* from here.

<sup>3</sup>This rule is not *removed* for a shallow clone that is sending commits: if the sender wants the history and the sending-clone doesn't have it, the sending-clone can't complete this push.  However, when the sender says *I'll give you commit `a123456`* it's possible for the receiver to say *ok, I'll take that one, I already have all its parents so no need to send any more history*.  So you *can* push from a shallow clone, as long as the clone you're pushing to already has the right history.