# Can I rebase and squash commits at the same time?

Tags: git

When I have a fix for a change that was a few commits earlier, I always wind up running rebase twice in a row. Is it possible to do this workflow all in one step? Let's say I have 4 new commits.

```
* (master) D
* C
* B
* A
* Base
```

I find a bug in B so I create a branch and fix it.

```
* (master) D
* C
| * (fix) Fix.
|/  
* B
* A
* Base
```

Next I run `git rebase --onto fix B D` to move C and D onto B.

```
* (master) D'
* C'
* (fix) Fix.
* B
* A
* Base
```

Finally I run `git rebase --i fix^^` to see the last few commits and I squash B and Fix into a single commit.

```
* (master) D'
* C'
* B'
* A
* Base
```

Is there a faster way to accomplish the same workflow? I imagine that merging would be easier, but merging is out for me because I'm using git svn which requires a linear history.

Comment: maybe the `fixup` and `autosquash` options could help here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history/2302947#2302947

Comment: @VonC Thanks, that will at least make these steps a little faster.

Comment: excellent (for a start). You could post an answer illustrating how the steps are faster with those options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the editor for the commit list in an interactive rebase shows up, you are free to add, remove or reorder commits to your liking. It's basically a way to influence the cherry-picking-in-a-loop that is going to take place (that's what rebase boils down to).

Comment: The ADD part is what I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you aware of the `--squash` option to `git merge`?

> `--squash`
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually make a commit or move the `HEAD`, nor record `$GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD` to cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit. This allows you to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).

Comment: +1 because I did not know about --squash. However this requires the same number of steps. After I've created the fix, instead of two rebases, I would need to do git merge --squash, then git commit at the head, and then git rebase -i to reorder and squash the fix into the commit with the bug.