# git workflow: everyone has a branch, or everyone has a master?

Tags: git, workflow

When working with multiple people with git, is it better

1. for everyone to just work in master, and merge between each other's masters, or
2. for everyone to work in their own titled branch?

As I see it, in the case of (1), although each master acts as a branch, everyone is expected to merge between each other's work with a mostly linear flow, whereas in (2), everyone is expected to merge a common master into *their* branch, and push changes from their branch into a common master when they are ready.

Can someone with experience working on medium- to large-sized teams with git make any comments?   What works best for your team?  I guess a third option is to always use feature branches instead of people branches, although I see this as being basically the same situation as (2) from this question's point of view.

I imagine that in both (1) and (2), a single person is responsible for pulling changes to the "official" master.  How would this carry over if more than one person as push access to the official master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Branch names in git are local to a repository.  `push` and `pull` can be configured to match identical names on a remote repository, but that's optional behavior.  If you have a central repository, you want `master` there to be definitive.  What individual developers call their working branches on their local repositories is really a matter of taste.  Some will have their local `master` be their working branch, and others will use a single named dev branch.

If your devs are up to it, the really savvy way is to use feature or topic branches, so that rather than having a "Mike's work" branch you have a "work on autofrotzification feature" branch that can be pushed and exchanged sanely without everyone needing to do a ton of early merging back and forth.

Comment: Yes, what you state in your first paragraph is basically my problem statement.  What I'm asking is what policy would you recommend?  If you have half your developers using master as their working branch, and half treating it as "ready to pull", it seems like it would be quite confusing.

Comment: My recommendation is really in the second paragraph.  Failing that, I would not worry about a policy for local branch naming on dev machine repositories.  All you need is a policy for when one can push to master on the authoritative server that everyone pulls from.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was picturing a situation where one person would push to official master.  That person would need to know how/when to pull from others.

Comment: Well, in that case, each dev would generally control two repositories -- one on their personal machine, and one on a server somewhere.  The server one would be a source for the gatekeeper pulls and master there would be "ready to pull"; again, what they do on their own boxes would be up to them.

Comment: Right, that sounds reasonable.  I use a two-repo set-up when using git personally.  The only thing is that I use it for backup and synchronization purposes, so doubling it for "publishing" is probably not a good idea.  However, since having a third repo on the same server for publishing comes at basically zero cost (since afaik git uses hard links to share objects between repos on the same file system), then maybe this is the best approach.

Comment: Yeah, extra repos on one machine are cheap.  However, if you want to avoid that, you can give each dev a named branch they can push to on the "main" repository.  You'd need to install a pre-receive-pack hook to so that kind of permissions check though.  The gatekeeper can then pull all the dev branches from the main repo, merge, and push to the main repo's 'master'.

Answer (score 0):

DVCS introduces the publication as an [othogonal dimension to branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563836/sell-me-distributed-revision-control/2563917#2563917).

That means branches in a DVCS have two roles:

1. the classic one: [code isolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100829/when-should-you-branch/2107672#2107672): you isolate the history (list of revisions) of a code in a branch
2. the new one: publication: you repicate your commits from repos to repos.

Git allows for "private commits", ie you commit as much as you want (and then you can [clean your history of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history/2302947#2302947)).
If you do that in master, this is not good for publication: since master is the branch visible by default when a repo is cloned, anyone cloning your repo won't get a stable state, but a snapshot of a work in progress.

Private commits means: commit in branches that aren't published.
You can call those whatever you want.

Any branch which is to be pushed/pulled should never be called after a resource name (like '`VonC_branch`'), but always after a feature or a more general release management topic (like '`public`', '`next`', '`patchV1`', ...)

The difference between the private branches and the public ones is the history of commits you allow in each one:

- as many commits you want in a private branch (you need just to assign the right comment to facilitate a future re-ordering through `rebase --interactive` with `!fixup` and `!squash` actions)
- "consistent" commits in public branches (each commit is complete, represent a stable state that at least compile and can be tested, even if those test fail)
  A master branch for instance would have even stricter standard than that (like "the tests *must* pass)

So to decide on how you will use branches with Git, you need to take into account the publication aspect.

Answer (score 0):

For a medium to large size team, you most likely want to have centralized repository, with the "official" `master` branch.

The other popular option would be to have an integrator, who is basically an intermediary between the developers and the central repo. How you decide upon this is reliant on what your team decides is the most appropriate method. There is a good write-up on the differences in the [Pro Git book](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html).

Going with a shared repo, it comes down to the developers personal preference (and some team agreement) whether to commit directly to their local `master`, or use a separate `dev` branch. My thought is that keeping local changes in a `dev` branch is a better option, but slightly more cumbersome for developers who are used to centralized SCM.

The benefit of the separate `dev` branch is that makes it easier to track new commits in the code base by just running `git pull` on `master`. The clean master lets the devs always check out the latest public code if necessary. If you `pull` with changes in `master`, it will merge in the `origin/master` branch onto your unpublished commits. This will create a new merge commit in the `master` and will be visible if the changes ever get pushed back to `master`. Maybe this is what you want, but it can make the commit history somewhat messing looking.

With a `dev` branch you can easily rebase against the `master` to keep the commit history linear. Without a `dev` branch, a `git pull --rebase` in `master` will have the same effect, but it is easy to forget this step.

Basically, using a private tracking branch (like `dev`) gives a developer a little more flexibility on how she accepts public changes into her local branches. It also makes it easier to keep the centralized repo free of excessive merge commits. The only downside is that it requires some additional effort from the developers, but in the long-term will enhance the ultimate utilization of git.

Comment: How are you going to test in dev if dev is always commits a head. If you use a centralize master to pull from. That is nothing but disaster.  Everyone should pull from dev. So what if the branch is not stabalized. If something is broken you create a ticket and pass it on or fix it. What needs to be done is create tags. You QA dev and tag it as a release version. that way you can revert back to the most stable nightly build. That goes for git hub. is something is broken you pull the nightly build to make sure you dont fix something that is already fixed. Otherwise Conflicts