# Git: Merge in branch without polluting the Master history

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, bazaar

OK so:

In svn and bzr, I can branch, commit, merge, and my commit history will look like this:

```
41: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Jump to list by name instead of number.
40: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] [m] Miscellaneous cleanups.
  39.1.4: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Removed old files.
  39.1.3: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed bug where test could not...
  39.1.2: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed a CSS layout bug from th...
  39.1.1: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed a typo.
39: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Added a progress bar.
38: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] Updated the core libraries.
  37.1.3: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Updated HTML Kickstarter.
  37.1.2: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Upgraded to from jQuery 1.8.3 to 2.0.3.
  37.1.1: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Upgraded to jQuery Address v1.6.
```

If I don't want to expand out the history, I can:

```
41: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Jump to list by name instead of number.
40: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] [m] Miscellaneous cleanups.
39: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Added a progress bar.
38: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] Updated the core libraries.
```

At any time, I can get diffs, etc. for the individual merged commits *quite* easy, via `bzr diff -r37.1.2..37.1.3`, for instance.

**What's important is that my branch history is *preserved* and my mainline commit history is NOT polluted by the minor feature commits.**

Now, whenever I do feature merges in git, however, with or without `--no-ff`, I get the following in my commit history:

```
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Jump to list by name instead of number.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] [m] Miscellaneous cleanups.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Removed old files.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Added a progress bar.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed bug where test could not...
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [merge] Updated the core libraries.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed a CSS layout bug from th...
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Updated HTML Kickstarter.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 [m] Fixed a typo.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Upgraded to from jQuery 1.8.3 to 2.0.3.
<hash>: Theodore R. Smith 2013-09-14 Upgraded to jQuery Address v1.6.
```

My problems with this are many fold.

1. The feature minor commits are *all* in the mainline history. What the hell?
2. The feature minor commits are *jumbled* in the mainline history. It seems they are stuck there based on their original commit time, not merge time ;o
3. There is no immediate numerical ranking of revision ids, only random hashes. But I bet that's not fixable.
4. I wouldn't have ANY idea where a feature branch ends or begins, based upon looking at this.

I want a solution that

1. Preserves all commit history, and lets me diff minor feature commits. This is needed for code forensics. So `git rebase` is out of the picture, as is `git merge --squash`.
2. Does NOT pollute the mainline commit log. This is probably the most severe.
3. KEEPS ALL OF THE COMMITS IN THE PROPER ORDER, based upon merge time. Please, I can't have minor commits being mixed-matched.
4. Optimally lets me at least see all of the minor feature commits, in the proper order, along with the mainline history, like how bzr does things, tho I don't mind only being able to view this info with a drill-in command, like `git log`.

Thank you for helping me understand this overly-complicated program!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge GIT branch without commit log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123077/merge-git-branch-without-commit-log)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The graph of Git and Bazaar are exactly the same, I know because I wrote Git's official Bazaar bridge, the only difference is how the graph is presented through the `log` command.

`git log` has tons of options so can specify exactly how you want that graph to be presented.

It looks like what you want is this:

```
git log --oneline --graph
```

Which will show you the merges in a similar way as `bzr log` does:

```
*   eaaec50 Merge git://github.com/git-l10n/git-po
|\  
| * 1b5f46f l10n: Add reference for french translation team
| * 6b388fc l10n: fr.po: 821/2112 messages translated
* |   2809258 Merge branch 'sb/mailmap-updates'
|\ \  
| * | cdb6b5a .mailmap: Combine more (name, email) to individual persons
| * | 10813e0 .mailmap: update long-lost friends with multiple defunct addresses
* | | 8ed205a git-remote-mediawiki: ignore generated git-mw
| |/  
|/|   
* |   96cb27a Merge branch 'maint'
```

You can also ignore the "minor commits" completely

```
git log --oneline --first-parent

eaaec50 Merge git://github.com/git-l10n/git-po
2809258 Merge branch 'sb/mailmap-updates'
8ed205a git-remote-mediawiki: ignore generated git-mw
96cb27a Merge branch 'maint'
```

If you get tired of typing all these options, you can configure an alias:

```
git config --global alias.l 'log --oneline --graph'
```

So you can just type `git l`.

Comment: why the heck isn't that the default? Particularly on github :o

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally have a usable git log ;o It doesn't work with github, but oh well, right?

Comment: Even better, you can use the `--decorate` option.