# Move changes back to mainline

Tags: git, version-control

Hi am trying to move my changes from the dev branch back to the mainline; without having all incremental commits show up in the history/log
.I was trying to do it with cherry-pick but guess I am doing something wrong.

Below is how my branches look like:

```
Branch Mainline :

commit A [introduced after I branched to dev from mainline]
commit B
commit C
.... so on

Branch  Dev:

Commit P  [not pushed to remote]
Commit Q  [not pushed to remote]
more than 10 different commits in between [pushed to remote dev branch]
Commit B [Based on mainline]

Required result in Branch Mainline:

Commit allDev [A single commit with everything from the dev branch after Commit B ]
Commit A [This might need a merge commit since overlapping code from dev]
Commit B
Commit C
... so on
```

Would be grateful if I could get some help here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123102/2303202

Comment: Has you problem been solved yet by referring below answer? If yes, you can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a squash merge. This will leave the incremental commits in the branch and create one new big commit in master. Assuming you are on a `feature` branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash feature
$ git commit
```

As per [git-merge docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> --squash
>
> --no-squash
>
> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge happened (except for the merge information), but do not actually
>   make a commit, move the HEAD, or record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD (to cause
>   the next git commit command to create a merge commit). This allows you
>   to create a single commit on top of the current branch whose effect is
>   the same as merging another branch (or more in case of an octopus).
>
> With --no-squash perform the merge and commit the result. This option
>   can be used to override --squash.