# Why would I want to do git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've seen lots of people talk about `git rebase` and what it does, e.g. [Hg: How to do a rebase like git's rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672351/hg-how-to-do-a-rebase-like-gits-rebase) and people talk about what it achieves (gives linear history), e.g. here [Git rebase loses history, then why rebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250817/git-rebase-loses-history-then-why-rebase) But I can't fathom why you would want to do this.

It seems like a **big** expense, to go back and revise your commit history (which must surely involve some ugly merges with n-way conflicts). And I could imagine cases where it could be very misleading, (e.g. if two people solve the same problem in different ways, but the history doesn't show their work as having occurred in parallel; seems that could easily lead to criticism and resentment too in some high-pressure coding environments).

What you gain is an easier to understand, but incorrect, history graph. What makes that worth the effort?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Great question - personally I avoid rebasing, for the exact reasons you mentioned. I guess it is a matter of personal preference, but I also prefer when the history graph shows what was really happening.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rebase is most useful when pushing a single commit or a small number of commits developed in a short time frame (hours or minutes).

Before pushing to a shared server, one must first pull the commits made to the origin's HEAD in the meantime—failing to do so would create a non-fast-forward push. In doing so, one can choose between a merge (`git pull`) or a rebase (`git pull --rebase`) operation. The merge option, while technically more appealing, creates an additional merge commit. For a small commit, the appearance of two commits per change actually makes the history *less* readable because the merge operation distracts from the commit's message.

In a typical shared development tree, every developer ends up pushing to a shared branch by doing some variation of `git pull; <resolve conflicts>; git push`. If they are using `git pull` without `--rebase`, what happens is that almost *every* commit ends up being accompanied by a merge commit, even though no parallel development was really going on. This creates an intertwined history from what is in reality a linear sequence of commits. For this reason, `git pull --rebase` is a better option for small changes resulting from short development, while a merge is reserved for integration of long-lived feature branches.

All this applies to rebasing *local* commits, or rebasing a short-lived feature branch shared by closely connected coworkers (sitting in the same room). Once a commit is pushed to a branch regularly followed by by others, it should **never** be rebased.

Comment: full agree; the only use of rebase in _my_ mind is exactly that one. I cannot get why some projects completely disallow merges in their history.

Comment: Disallowing merges sounds like a knee-jerk reaction to the multitude of spurious merges described in the answer. It's the wrong reaction, but I kind of understand it after seeing the graph of commits that my coworkers (myself included) created immediately after we started using git some years ago—it looked more like a printed circuit board than like a history of commits.

Comment: Anyone who has banned merges probably hasn't learned about `git log --no-merges`

Comment: `git log --no-merges` is fine, but you do and normally *want* to see merges in tools like `tig` and `gitk`. In my team we banned *trivial* merges, those that merge a single small commit. (And the ban is enforced in a purely, *ahem*, social way.)

Comment: @user4815162342 exactly my thought about it

Answer (score 6):

**TLDR: Rebase strategy is not worth the effort.**

The only **benefit** of rebase strategy is linear history and that's it.

Now ask yourself a question how many times you have checked git history to figure out something? Would you be able to solve it with a merge strategy?

My answer is almost never and yes merge strategy is not great but good enough.

But here comes the **cost** of rebasing strategy:

- you have to rebase your changes each time someone else pushes changes to the main branch, it is fine for 3 devs but for more, it becomes a problem, add to it waiting for a pipeline to build and it becomes a horror to merge anything.
- you can only "merge" one change at a time to the main branch all others has to be rebased first and build by pipeline again (extra delay).
- resolving conflict has to be done for each commit separately, resolving conflicts for older/outdated commits is insane to me if I know that I have changed it in the next commit.
- if you mess up rebase you would add all the fixes to the last commit and all the older ones would stay broken. The alternative is to start everything all over again.
- you have to force push to your branch after rebase, if you mess it up you may spend long hours scanning reflog.
- if you have more than two commits on your branch you likely squash them before rebase to have less work and you lose your precious commit history.

I have tried both and when I compare benefits with downsides the Rebase strategy is not worth an effort.

Answer (score 4):

Performing a rebase usually involves no more conflict resolution than a merge, so the expense compared to that is minimal (just the time it takes to replay your commits, really).

As with most things related to git, you should only rebase if you know *what* you're doing, and *why* you're doing it. Here are some of my reasons for rebasing:

- I've worked on a patch series that hasn't touched any components that have been altered upstream in the meantime. A merge commit wouldn't contain any useful information in this case.
- I'm about to submit a pull request on [GitHub](http://www.github.com), and the merge commit required would be a lot of work. By rebasing first, I make the pull request easier for the upstream owner to handle. Certainly I could merge instead, but as they've never seen my code before, that will just make the patch series harder to read.
- I'm merging changes in from upstream, and there are a large number of conflicts. `git rebase` lets me resolve these conflicts on commit at a time, making it easier to understand, and test as I go. If I care about maintaining a merge commit, I can just go back afterwards to a non-rebased version of the branch, merge it with upstream, then use the diff against the rebased version as the conflict resolving merge commit.

Comment: "so the expense compared to that is minimal" my experience that it is a visible expense in a dev work and you should ask yourself twice if you really benefit from linear history.