# github pull requests: Conflicting advice on commit ranges?

Tags: git, github, patch, pull-request

I know about using branches for multiple pull requests, that's fine.

But what about this scenario:

- Dave is the upstream repo, master branch "Dave/A"
- Satish forks the repo, creates branch B, and sends a pull request against Dave/A
- Satish then creates branch C from Satish/B, and let's assume that **C requires B**
- Satish wants to create another pull request, this time for branch C

I've found two conflicting sets of advice (but perhaps the dependency on B is different)

[Advice from GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) seems to say C should be applied against A:

> Changing the base repository changes who is notified of the pull
>   request. Everyone that can push to the base repository will receive an
>   email notification and see the new pull request in their dashboard the
>   next time they sign in.

This would seem to apply in this case for two reasons:

1. Satish wants **Dave** to take action; Satish already knows about the other branch
2. If Dave were to only apply B->C then the patch wouldn't even work

But this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9843484/295802) says the opposite, that C should be applied against B.  Note that his scenario is `a->b->c->d->e`, vs. my simpler `A->B->C`.

> Make another request. For the base, type in the commit number of C,
>   and for the head, put E (yours/master).

*This is equivalent to B->C range in my scenario.*

To me, both arguments make some amount of sense.  Which is *correct*?

I'm guessing that the answer is "it depends...", but I'd really appreciate the walkthrough.  It feels like there's at least three issues here:

1. Who gets notified
2. Whether or not all pull requests are assumed to be functional
3. Visibility / isolation of each set of changes, for easier inspection

Thoughts???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a communication problem, more than a Git issue.

I prefer making separate PR, as their *intent* and *scope* differs.

But, in the PR message, one must clearly states if that PR is suppose to *supersede* another PR.

That way, the original repo project manager can try those different PR separately, gauging their effects, and select the appropriate one.

He can then ask initial contributors to redo their PR (on their same branch) based on the work of the PR he or she finally selected.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still a bit ambiguous.  You say "I prefer making separate PR", as both scenarios would be "separate" in some sense. Did you mean "A->B" and "B->C", or "A->B" and "A->C" ?  Thanks

Comment: @MarkBennett A->B, and A->C. Once B is approved, Satish can rebase C on top of the (now merged) B, and force push to update the second PR.

Comment: Marking as answered, but still happy to hear other opinions.  I'll also try to be a bit clearer in the future about what supersedes what.

Comment: I used to do what @VonC is recommending (A->B, A->C) but it's not so great if someone wants to review them out of order or I'm not around to rebase. These days I just don't make the second pull until the first one is merged.

Comment: @All I agree, that can be a viable alternative.