# Multiple Forks of git-repo in my own account (or: how to deal with multiple pull requests simultaneously?)

Tags: git, github

**this is related: [How to open multiple pull requests on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450036/how-to-open-multiple-pull-requests-on-github)**

I am trying to have multiple forks of someone else's repo. (I will have to work on multiple issues simultaneously and there will by several pull-requests in parallel, maybe there is another best practice do this without multiple forks?)

I am following this guide here: https://adrianshort.org/create-multiple-forks-of-a-github-repo/

But I get this error.

> error: src refspec master does not match any.

when trying to push.

I suspect that I am on a completely wrong track anyway. There probably is a standard way to issue multiple pull-requests from just one fork?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another best practice. That's what git branches are for. You are not limited to one pull request per fork. You aren't even limited to one pull request per **branch**.

**[Look it up](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)**

To update yourself against the original, you need to use [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote.html) to add the original as another remote, and then use `git fetch` or `git pull` from the original, to fetch commits to the local environment (and perhaps push them to your fork).

**[Moar reading](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple branches on a single fork. When you issue a pull request, specify which branch to pull.

Comment: how can I pull in the latest commits of the original repo after opening a new branch on my fork?

Comment: `git fetch` and then `git merge origin/master`