# Make a new Pull Request on the same branch where the last commit hasn't been merged yet

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Okay ... here's the situation:

- I forked a repository
- I made a new branch. the branch name is `configs`
- I committed a few changes and made pull request #1
- Pull request #1 is still being reviewed and has not been merged on the base repository
- I made a few more changes. still in the `configs` branch. but this new change does not affect previous changes (different files)
- I made a new commit and of course it is still in `configs` brach
- When I look at github, this new commit will go to the previous pull request, pull request #1.

Well, my question is **"How do you make this new commit as a new pull request or lets say pull request #2 but still in the same brach?"**

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open multiple pull requests on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450036/how-to-open-multiple-pull-requests-on-github)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your second commit on another branch

```
# now

A---B---C <<< main-line
         \
          D---E <<< configs

# target

A---B---C <<< main-line
         \
          D <<< configs
           \
            E <<< configs-plus
```

To achieve that, step by step :

```
# start from branch configs
git checkout configs

# Create the new branch (by default, it'll point at HEAD, so configs)
git branch configs-plus

# reset current branch (still configs) to last commit
git reset --hard @^

# finally, push (--force (or -f) needed because history has been rewritten)
git push -f origin HEAD
```

Then create a new PR `configs-plus > main-line`. The first PR will have been updated by the force push to remove the second commit.

Comment: thanks it works ! we can also use git stash and git stash pop to take any working changes to the new branch.