# How to create parallel pull requests to the same branch github

Tags: github

So there is a repo of an organization on github which I have cloned to make contributions.
I made my first contribution (solving an issue) from `tantheta01:master -> organization_name:master` which consisted of 3 commits
Now I want to contribute to another contribution. My first contribution has not been merged. If I use the same `tantheta01:master` branch to commit and then open another PR, the old PR shall become updated of the new contents. AND the second PR would contain commits from the first PR. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: create a branch for each contribution

Comment: Pull Requests are per branch. You cannot cretae multiple PRs for same branch. However, if you push again to a branch which already has an opened PR then that PR gets updated with your newly pushed commits. Similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8450535/2915738)

Comment: If previous PR has not merged then any commits that you push to your repo will become part of existing PR. This is the reason that new PR requires a different branch. Since, this is an old issue, you would have figured this by now.   :-) Commenting for others