# Git alias to squash all commits with a particular commit message

Tags: git, alias

I've been using this git-alias which I got from a question on here:

`wip = !f() { git add -A; git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 git rm; git commit -m "wip";}; f`

So now I have a series of n commits, sequentially, which all contain 'wip' on its own as the commit message.

How do I make a git alias to go about finding the right number of commits back up the tree which contain "wip" and squashes them? Is it actually possible?

Comment: If you had `fixup!` instead of `wip`, you might try a `git rebase --interactive --autosquash` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302736/trimming-git-checkins-squashing-git-history/2302947#2302947)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to interactively `rebase` and squash the existing `wip` commits. Since a `rebase` with squashes will change history, it makes it difficult (though not impossible) to automate; it's best to `rebase` on a case-by-case basis. After doing this, you can change your `wip` alias to the following:

```
git config --global alias.wip '!f() { git add -A; git ls-files --deleted -z | xargs -0 -r git rm; s=`git show --format=%s HEAD | head -1`; if [ "wip" = "$s" ]; then git commit --amend -m "wip"; else git commit -m "wip"; fi;}; f'
```

This would avoid contiguous `wip` commits in your history. The alias is changed from your original alias by using the [`xargs` `-r` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) so that `If the standard input is completely empty, do not run the command.` and if the current `HEAD` commit subject is `wip`, use `commit`'s `--amend`.