# Remove version history of a single file in Git

Tags: git, version-control, git-clone

Use-Case:

**I am creating a clone of my repository and I wish to maintain the version history of every other file but one, lets call it "black-sheep.json"**

---

Following is the only approach I've discovered as yet:

1. Create a temporary copy of black-sheep.json, say tmp.json
2. Then remove all history for black-sheep.json using this command

> ```
> git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
>   'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch black-sheep.json' \
>   --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
> ```

.3. Lastly rename the tmp.json to black-sheep.json

I don't like this solution! Is there a better way ?

---

I just realized another approach, I can squash all the commits for this particular file into a single commit.

However in this approach I have the following doubts

- How to do this in a non-interactive mode ?
- How to do this across multiple non-sequential commits ?

**NOTE:**

- All commits include only a single file.
- I need to implement this in code.

Answer (score 1):

> 1/ How to do this in a non-interactive mode ?

The only solution I know of would use a [`git rebase --interactive --autosquash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302947/6309), but it is based on identical commit messages: if you don't have those, you would need to:

- first, `rebase --interactive` in order to edit those messages
- second, use the autosquash

But that would ruin the "non-interactive" part of the process.

> 2/ How to do this across multiple non-sequential commits ?

That is what `autosquash` does, but in my opinion, the `git filter-branch` remains the omre precise tool to do what you want in *one* (non-interactive) step.
Another tool could be [BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), if you don't like the syntax of the `git filter-branch` command.

Answer (score 1):

[JGit](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RebaseCommand.html) does provide an API for doing a interactive rebase.

But I decided to keep it simple and rename the file to append it with a new version number each time I clone the repository.

> So **back-sheep_revA.json** in the new revision becomes
>   **black-sheep_revB.json**
>
> And delete black-sheep_revA.json

It's not a very refined approach but it keeps the complexity low and get the job done (remove the history for black-sheep.json)