# Are there any real differences between using "fixup!" or "squash!"?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

I've been reading git documentation on [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) and [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), but I still don't understand the difference between using `fixup!` or `squash!` as a prefix for the commit message when doing a `rebase --autosquash`.  I believe I understand what `fixup!` does in terms of [fixing previous commits](http://fle.github.io/git-tip-keep-your-branch-clean-with-fixup-and-autosquash.html), but I fail to see a good example where `squash!` is used instead.  Can anyone clarify the difference between the two and give some context where they would be used differently?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would the second part of my old answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2302947/6309 provide a decent example of `squash!` usage?

Comment: @VonC It took me a while to absorb, but yes!  This answers my question.  And just to be sure I understand, using `squash!` will guarantee that the squashing operation is recorded in the history, which is unlike `fixup!` where the squash operation is invisible for a more "cleaner" approach.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the gist of it. I have added an answer to extract from my older (and way too long) answer what is interesting here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I illustrated in "[Trimming Git Commits/Squashing Git History](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302947/6309)", and to summarize:

> with the fixup! directive, you could keep that squashing "invisible" in the commit message, while still benefiting from the automatic commit reordering with the `--autosquash` option

As the [Op Dash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6312047/dash) comments:

> Using `squash!` will guarantee that the squashing operation is recorded in the history, which is unlike `fixup!` where the squash operation is invisible for a more "cleaner" approach.

---

Another difference, *before* Git 2.16.x/2.17 (Q1 2018), is that you could not combined "`git commit --fixup`" with an additional commit *message*.
This is now no longer the case.

See [commit 30884c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30884c9afcd03aa7d9a0524fde3c96d2e29cf9a9) (22 Dec 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason -- `avar` --](https://github.com/avar) in [commit 30884c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30884c9afcd03aa7d9a0524fde3c96d2e29cf9a9), 22 Dec 2017)</sup>

> ### `commit`: add support for `--fixup <commit> -m"<extra message>"`
>
> Add support for supplying the `-m` option with `--fixup`.
>   Doing so has errored out ("Option `-m` cannot be
>   combined") ever since `--fixup` was introduced.
>   Before this, the only way to amend the fixup message while committing was to use `--edit` and amend it in the editor.
>
> The use-case for this feature is one of:
>
> - Leaving a quick note to self when creating a `--fixup` commit when
>     it's not self-evident why the commit should be squashed without a
>     note into another one.
> - (Ab)using the `--fixup` feature to "fix up" commits that have already
>     been pushed to a branch that doesn't allow non-fast-forwards,
>     i.e. just noting "`this should have been part of that other commit`",
>     and if the history ever got rewritten in the future the two should
>     be combined.
>
> In such a case you might want to leave a small message,
>     e.g. "`forgot this part, which broke XYZ`".

---

Note that before Git 2.17 (Q2 2018) "`git commit --fixup`" did not allow "`-m<message>`" option to be used at the same time; allow it to annotate resulting commit with more text.

See [commit 30884c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/30884c9afcd03aa7d9a0524fde3c96d2e29cf9a9), [commit f55e84f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f55e84fff9b53e532a874f39384a3bcbb9292f28) (22 Dec 2017) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
Helped-by: [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c1ab3b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1ab3b8a44149a8dfb8968a958b13ac9e8d9579a), 27 Feb 2018)</sup>

> ### `commit`: add support for `--fixup <commit> -m"<extra message>"`
>
> Add support for supplying the `-m` option with `--fixup`. Doing so has
>   errored out ever since `--fixup` was introduced. Before this, the only
>   way to amend the fixup message while committing was to use `--edit` and
>   amend it in the editor.

The use-case for this feature is one of:

> - Leaving a quick note to self when creating a `--fixup` commit when
>     it's not self-evident why the commit should be squashed without a
>     note into another one.
> - (Ab)using the `--fixup` feature to "fix up" commits that have already
>     been pushed to a branch that doesn't allow non-fast-forwards,
>     i.e. just noting "this should have been part of that other commit",
>     and if the history ever got rewritten in the future the two should
>     be combined.
>
>   In such a case you might want to leave a small message,
>     e.g. "forgot this part, which broke XYZ".
>
> With this, `--fixup <commit> -m"More" -m"Details"` will result in a
>   commit message like:
>
> ```
> !fixup <subject of <commit>>
>
> More
>
> Details
> ```
>
> When the `--fixup` option was initially added the "Option `-m` cannot be
>   combined" error was expanded from `-c`, `-C` and `-F` to also include
>   `--fixup` ([commit d71b8ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d71b8ba7c959e414d36974af890e3e2cbd2acbb9), "commit: --fixup option for use with `rebase --autosquash`", 2010-11-02, Git 1.7.4-rc0)).